# index() requires QueryKeyExpression with CollectionMapping that has non-null list order column

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, querydsl, booleanquery

I have two entities, One saves the basic case related data and other saves all the updates for a certain case.

```
@Entity(name = "Case")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@NamedQueries({
public class Case extends AbstractAuditableEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long referenceId; 

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Incident Incident;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = CaseUpdate.class, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "case")
    @JoinColumn(name="case", nullable = false)
    @OrderBy("created desc")
    private List<CaseUpdate> caseUpdates = new ArrayList<CaseUpdate>();
```

The other class with ManyToOne relationship is as follows

```
@Entity(name = "CaseUpdate")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)

public class CaseUpdate extends AbstractAuditableEntity implements Serializable {

    public CaseUpdate() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String status;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String type;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "created",nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date restoreDate;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date responseDate;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date commitmentDate;

    @JoinColumn(name="caseUpdates")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Case case;
```

I am trying to search the Case table and CaseUpdate table using BooleanExpression to build queries. When it tries to search I get exception

> Caused by: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException: 
>   Exception Description: index() requires QueryKeyExpression with CollectionMapping that has non-null list order column. [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToManyMapping[caseUpdates]] in does not meet this condition in [
>   Query Key caseUpdates
>      Base au.net.iinet.fms.data.entities.Case]
>   Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=Case jpql=
>   `"select count(case)
>   from Case case
>     left join case.caseUpdates as case_caseUpdates_0
>   where index(case_caseUpdates_0) = ?1 and case.faultIncident.faultDomain = ?2 and case_caseUpdates_0.status = ?3")`

The following code is used to create the search criteria

```
    BooleanExpression overallCriteria = null;
if (params.getStatus() != null && !params.getStatus().isEmpty()) {
      overallCriteria  = QCase.case.caseUpdates.get(0).status.eq(params.getStatus());
    }
```

The QCase class is generated using Querydsl.
I am not sure what this exception means and how to fix it, any ideas?

Comment: Since you can't be bothered to put the JPQL clearly, here it is `select count(case) from Case case left join case.caseUpdates as case_caseUpdates_0 where index(case_caseUpdates_0) = ?1 and case.faultIncident.faultDomain = ?2 and case_caseUpdates_0.status = ?3` and you can see easily enough that you have `INDEX(case_caseUpdates_0)`, whereas INDEX is supposed to take a collection field (e.g `caseUpdates`)

Comment: I am trying to understand this code which is already written, the caseUpdates is actually a List in entity Case. This is as far as I understand is trying to retrieve the last CaseUpdate from the array.

Comment: So you're using QueryDSL to generate this, and NOT the JPA API. Tags now updated

Comment: I have added the code that actually creates the query for searching. The JPQL was automatically generated, so I need to find the root cause and how to fix that.